# How to check if firebase service is available?

Tags: android, firebase

In cases when the app is running behind a firewall or there is a network outage or some sort of censorship, How can we check using code to see if the app can access the firebase systems?

Comment: would be helpful if the downvoter explained the reasoning.

Comment: *not the downvoter* What Firebase feature are you specifically looking to use, because the answer is likely different for many of them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , i'm using a lot of them(auth,database, fcm, storage). My problem is a code is failing continuously that may be due to internet restrictions(I.e, it would work with a different ISP). That's a case i'm seeing  that i need to handle.

Comment: You can check whether your app has network connectivity. But that won't mean they can access each Firebase feature. For the Database, you can [detect the connection state by listening for `.info/connected`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state). For Storage you could check for a known (small) marker image, etc. Since each service operates independently, it's different for each and not generically answerable.

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if Google Play Service is available like this:

```
/**
* Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If it
* doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from the
* Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
*/
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Context context) {
    int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
            (context);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.i(TAG, "This device does not support Google Play Services. " +
                "Push notifications are not supported");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You need to add the following line to your `build.gradle` also.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'`

Comment: Interesting approach. Many android users do not know google services are not available in all countries around the globe. Some countries ban google play services. Sometime the question is not if it's available right now, connected, disconnected... but if it was ever available. This kind of check could help in determine that...

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing currently there is no way you can check whether Firebase is available or not from codes inside the app. However you can check if Firebase itself is working fine by checking Firebase Status Dashboard.

In this site you can also find in what date Firebase service was not available or unstable in the past.

Hope it helps in some way.

https://status.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

As the

```
FirebaseApp.getInstance() throws IllegalStateException
```

you my try below solution

```
private val isFirebaseEnabled: Boolean
    get() {
        return try {
            FirebaseApp.getInstance() != null.   //that is always true, nevertheless it will throw exception if Firebase is not available
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            false
        }
    }
```

unfortunately it won't check actual network restrictions. You may try to ping FCM and catch connection timeout. E.g.

```
private fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val connection = URL("https://theUrl.com").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test")
        connection.connectTimeout = 10000
        connection.connect()
        connection.disconnect()
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false
    }
}
```